# API calls and the Cache of MetaTags

Tags: caching, tags, soundcloud

I have a tagging strategy for my client. There are a couple of specific tags that change quarterly. I recently updated one of the tags removing it from one track and applying it to another, and after 3 days it is still returning the old track. Any ideas on this?

Comment: could you please provide an example of such requests? does direct request to the track show outdated tags?

Comment: I am not at my code base right now. The behavior even occurs on SoundCloud not just the API, it has finally now rolled over. I went to TrackA and removed the tag indextrk and saved. I went to TrackB and added the tag indextrk and saved. For three days I enter the tag indextrk into search on the site, it returns trackA even though indextrk does not show up in the tags for that track. I will give a more technical answer later.